# Responsive image size

Tags: css, html

what I would like to achive is to change picture size depend on the size of the screen. I know it can be done with @media query in css, but I would like to achive this in "img" attribute.

I tried like this, but it does not work in my case.

```
 <picture>
  <source srcset="{{'payments_pink.png' |  file_img_url:'60px'}}" media="(min-width: 1200px)"/>
  <source srcset="{{'payments_pink.png' |  file_img_url:'40px'}}" media="(max-width: 800px)"/>
  <source srcset="{{'payments_pink.png' |  file_img_url:'10px'}}" media="(min-width: 600px)"/>
  <img src="{{'payments_pink.png' |  file_img_url:'40'}}" alt="example"/>
</picture>
```

tnx

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: It is working. I was having some mistake in code above pasted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `img {width: 100%}` and set the parent element of the `img` to `max-width:{preferred width}`. The image should automatically adjust to its parent element and the parent element should shrink when the viewport is smaller than the declared width